# MAUI - Plugin.Firebase: System.NullReferenceException: at Plugin.Firebase.CloudMessaging.FirebaseCloudMessagingImplementation.GetTokenAsync()

Tags: maui

I am getting below exception on the iOS platform for creating FCM Token.

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
> at Plugin.Firebase.CloudMessaging.FirebaseCloudMessagingImplementation.GetTokenAsync()

**My FCM Token Code:**

```
await CrossFirebaseCloudMessaging.Current.CheckIfValidAsync();
var token = await CrossFirebaseCloudMessaging.Current.GetTokenAsync();
```

I did below set up on iOS platform:

1. On the apple developer website and choose the Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles. Opened Identifiers and choose the app’s identifier. Then added Push Notification service into the identifier
2. Created a new provisioning profile, installed it on the device and binded it to the project settings.
3. Opened the apple developer website and choosed the Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles. Opened Keys from that and created a new key.(.P8 file) Downloaded it and uploaded it into the FCM console.
4. Enabled Remote Notifications on Info.plist and Entitlements.plist.
5. Added the below codes on AppDelegate.cs file.

   using Plugin.Firebase.DynamicLinks;

   public override bool ContinueUserActivity(UIApplication application, NSUserActivity userActivity, UIApplicationRestorationHandler completionHandler)
   {
   FirebaseDynamicLinksImplementation.ContinueUserActivity(application, userActivity, completionHandler);
   return base.ContinueUserActivity(application, userActivity, completionHandler);
   }

   public override bool OpenUrl(UIApplication application, NSUrl url, NSDictionary options)
   {
   FirebaseDynamicLinksImplementation.OpenUrl(application, url, options);
   return base.OpenUrl(application, url, options);
   }

Is any other set up is pending on iOS platform? Is it a known issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can refer to this issue:[Need testing with iOS simulator](https://github.com/TobiasBuchholz/Plugin.Firebase/issues/107).

It has the similar issue as yours. And according to the comment in it, this is because the `GetTokenAsync()` runs before the plugin's initialization.

So you can add the following code in the MauiProgram.cs:

```
events.AddiOS(iOS => iOS.WillFinishLaunching((app, launchOptions) => { CrossFirebase.Initialize(app, launchOptions, CreateCrossFirebaseSettings()); return false; }));
```

And then call the code about getting token in the AppShell's OnHandlerChanged method.

Comment: The code you provided has errors like this:https://i.stack.imgur.com/Or7MT.png

Comment: But when I updated `FinishedLaunching` with `WillFinishLaunching` the token is generating. Is that okay for the proper working or should I fix the errors and used the codes on the answer?

Comment: No, you don't have to. The key is make the getting token run after the initialization. @MatthewPans